# PHP file handling and fread error

Tags: php, function, fopen, filesize, fread

i'm working on PHP file handling:

i have two question:

In the following function i have this error : 
Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs...

and my function is:

```
function readingFile($file,$mode) {
    if (gettype($file) !== 'string' && gettype($mode) !== 'string') {
       return 'Pleas enter a file name and mode';
    }
    fopen($file,$mode) or die ('File Not Exist!!');
    $size = filesize($file);
    return fread($file,$size);
}
echo readingFile('file_1.txt','r');
```

1) how can i fix that?

2) when i write the following code and then press the enter i get a (False) in the first of next row. my mean's:

```
$size = filesize('file.txt'); // i press enter
False      //here i get this word
```

or

```
$file = fopen('file.txt','r'); // i press enter
False     // here i get this word
```

what is that?do not correct my codes?

in addition i'm using notepad++.

Comment: RTFM? [fread()](http://php.net/fread): `Parameters: handle: A file system pointer resource that is typically created using fopen().`

Comment: Why don't you just use `file_get_contents?

Comment: I am trying to have a good understanding of all the functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fread` takes a file handle as a first parameter (not a filename), so you need to change your code like this:

```
$handle = fopen($file,$mode) or die ('File Not Exist!!');
$size = filesize($file);
return fread($handle,$size);
```

Also if you want to read the entire file, a more straightforward method is `file_get_contents`. The code would then just be:

```
return file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: Regarding the second question, I find myself answer. the Nppcalc plug-in for notepad ++ would cause errors.